# Why is it that John Chrysostom is almost never referred to as "John Golden Mouth" in English?

Tags: names, nicknames

Why is it that the sainted [John Chrysostom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Chrysostom) (b. 347?, d. 407; Archbishop of Constantinople, 397–407) is almost never referred to as "John Golden Mouth" in English? ("Chrysostom" means "Golden Mouth" in Greek.) Would "John Golden Mouth" sound somewhat inappropriate or somewhat weird in English? Compare how we change Vlad Țepeș to Vlad the Impaler.

Comment: Why would you "translate" someone's name? Yes, that would be weird.

Comment: Exactly What JLG says - otherwise where would it end? Would you expect people to call me (Matthew Ellen) Gift of God of light?

Comment: @JLG - Because it's not his name, but rather his nickname. And we have bunch of cases with nicknames being translated, for example, Saint Basil the Great, Ivan the Terrible, Vlad the Impaler, etc.

Comment: @Brilliant - I have cleared up your question to make it clear what you are talking about. I've not heard of this guy until just now.

Comment: @MattЭллен - "Why is it that John Chrysostom John Chrysostom, the nickname of the Saint, is almost never referred to as "John Golden Mouth" in English" - It sounds a bit wrong to me, because people are not referring to his nickname, but rather to his very person.

Comment: @brilliant good point. Feel free to correct it some more. I've removed the bit about the nickname.

Comment: @JLG Names, particularly given names, get translated all the time. See my comment to @AndrewLeach’s answer. Then again, Mozart’s baptismal name was *Johannes Chrysostomus Wolfgangus Theophilus Mozart*, and not even he used that one. But Ива́н Гро́зный is normally Ivan the Terrible. Translating proper nouns is odd, but it happens: like how it’s really *Sevilla*, not *Seville*.

Comment: I remember Victor Borge saying something about Guisseppe Verdi. (Joe Green to you)...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, the Greek is *Χρυσόστομος*, so writing *Chrysostom* is in some fashion already an Anglicized translation, since we have  transliterated *Χ* (chi) > *Ch* and have dropped the *-ος* at the end. Mozart kept the Latinized *Johannes Chrysostomus* in his own name.

I have another reason, though.  The nickname *Χρυσόστομος* shouldn’t really be translated into English “golden mouth”, or else you’ll lose its true meaning.  The culturally correct version for English is actually “silver-tongued”, because that’s the corresponding idiom in English used to refer to one’s eloquence in speaking.

However, sometimes we really do get to read  *Ἰωάννης ὁ Χρυσόστομος* fully translated, as Maggilory did when in 1871 he published his work, *John of the Golden Mouth*.

I still think *John the Silver-Tongued* sounds better in English, because you have to translate the sense, not the words.

Comment: Does the Greek term have the same negative (or perhaps more accurately, dismissive) connotations that "silver-tongued" does in English? It would be a shame to pick up unintended connotations in an attempt to make a better translation.

Comment: @T.E.D. I don’t think of it that way, at least, not by itself.The OED says of *silver-tongued* “Eloquent, persuasive, sweet-spoken.” None of its citations have any negative connotations. There is also the citation of “His tongue was silver and his heart was fire.” Perhaps you have some contamination with the *devil* part of “silver-tongued devil” tainting the earlier portion of the expression.

Comment: I agree with T.E.D., there can  definitely be some association with deception, as noted on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Tongue). I expect this is from "silver-tongued devil".

Comment: See also [here](http://www.englishforums.com/English/GoldenTongue/mdgc/post.htm).

Answer (score 9):

St. John Chrysostom is very rarely called "Golden Mouth" in English, because there is no English idiom "golden mouth". It sounds very strange and unintentionally hilarious.

However, there *is* an English idiom "golden-tongued", and lo and behold [St. John Chrysostom is sometimes called St. John the Golden-Tongued](http://www.google.com/webhp?oq=saint+john+golden+tongued&oq=saint+john+golden+tongued#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=st+john+golden+tongued&oq=st+john+golden+tongued&gs_l=hp.3...11683.16640.0.16807.28.24.3.1.1.0.126.2105.20j4.24.0...0.0...1c.PKpw1Ck6BF4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=51a6e4b639342c8a&biw=1920&bih=979).

Answer (score 5):

Where a name or nickname can be reasonably rendered by English-speakers, generally it's not translated. Chrysostom is easily said, as is Charles André Joseph Marie de Gaulle — we don't render his name as "Charles Andrew French". Even a transliterated name like Aung San Suu Kyi is reasonably easy once you know how to say it.

However a name which can't easily be transliterated like Tȟatȟáŋka Íyotake may well be translated. Most people have heard of Sitting Bull.

Comment: I’ve always found Iberian practice in this area peculiar. When writing English-language texts, the Spanish never translate kings named things like Juan Carlos or Alfonso into John Charles or Alphonse, yet the Portuguese regularly translate their own João  or Alfonso into John and Alphonse. I have no idea why. Similarly, you don’t hear Juana la Loca called Crazy Jane, although you probably should (or at least, I like the sound of it :). I think this used to be more common than today: witness the many names for Christopher Columbus.

Comment: It was common until the 18C to Latinise names when writing them, especially in academic texts. So 'Johannes' Kepler, except when the English want to claim someone, Giovanni Caboto = John Cabot

Comment: The Chinese philosopher **Kong Fuzi** (a transliteration, meaning *Master Kong*) is regularly referred to as **Confucius** in the West, even at a housing development in NYC called *Confucius Plaza*, which is lived in by mostly Chinese speaking people.

Answer (score 4):

[Catholic Online](http://www.catholic.org/saints/stindex.php?lst=J) lists more than 200 saints named John, although a dozen or so are duplicate entries. Some of these saints, including St. John Chrysostom ("St. John the Golden Mouthed"), are distinguished from the mob of other St. Johns by descriptive names that include terms not translated into English. Among these are St. John Angeloptes ("St. John, the man who saw an angel"); St John Calabytes ("St. John of the small hut [*calybe*]"); St. John Cantius ("St. John of Canty"); St. John Climacus ("St. John, author of *The Climax, or The Ladder to Perfection*"), also known as St. John Scholasticus ("St. John the scholar"); St. John Duns Scotus ("St. John Duns, the Scot"); St. John Grande [Pecador] (St. John the Great [Sinner])"; St. John Nepomucene ("St. John of Nepomuk"); and St. John Theristus ("St. John the Harvester").

The Church has by no means been consistent in its approach toward translating these descriptive names. For example, Catholic Online also lists St. John the Apostle, St. John the Baptist, St. John Camillus the Good, St. John of the Cross, St. John the Dwarf, St. John the Evangelist, St. John of God, St. John the Merciful, St. John of the Goths, St. John of the Grating, St. John the Almoner [Almsgiver], St. John the Silent, St. John the Wonder-Worker, etc., etc.

I don't see any consistent principle underlying the decision to fully translate a particular St. John's name into English or to leave it incompletely translated. Undoubtedly some of the saints' names were thoroughly familiar to learned churchmen by their Greek or Latin cognomens; and much later, when the names reached the vulgar populace, those less well-informed people perhaps didn't realize that the names could have been further translated into English words. Or perhaps they simply acceded to established Church preferences in name identification—a result that would make sense given the Church's primary and continuing interest in identifying its own saints.

In any event, even aside from lists of saints, John Chrysostom is certainly not unique in bearing an incompletely translated name in standard English. Consider Charlemagne (aka Carolus Magnus, but only rarely in English Charles the Great) and Magna Carta (far more familiar and immediately recognizable to most English speakers under that name than as Great Charter). My conclusion is that proper names become established in English by many and varied paths, and the question of why one such name emerges in one form and another in another may be unanswerable.

---

A somewhat similar situation involving the standard English form of a Greek name is that of the legendary esoteric philosopher, [Hermes Trismegistus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermes_Trismegistus). I doubt that many English speakers are aware that the name actually means "Thrice-Greatest Hermes," because *Trismegistus* remains untranslated in standard English usage. Admittedly, however, the first name *Hermes* doesn't seem anglicized in the way that the first name *John* does.